# New missing/unsatisfied dependencies - JBoss 7 EAP

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7

Find below the error seen on console when RepoWeb.war is deployed to JBOSS 7 EAP server

```
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:

      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindErrorsTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.BindTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EscapeBodyTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."com.karthik.service.RepoImpl".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
      service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".component."com.karthik.servlet.RepoServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."RepoWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService]
```

I extracted RepoWeb.war deployed on the server and found the required jars in WEB-INF/lib folder -
**spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3.jar, spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, etc..**
and also the **RepoImpl.class and RepoServlet.class** in the classes folder.

Why I am getting the above error even though the war(RepoWeb.war) deployed on server contains the necessary jars and classes.

Comment: There should be something further up the log with more information.

Comment: Have you got the answer ? I am facing simillar issue with no luck.